# Ruby: Check multiple keys in hash and delete it

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to check if the given both keys is present in hash. Checking is not the problem here but one of the keys may not be present and can return false. I need to delete only the keys that are present.

```
if model_changes.has_key?(name)
   model_changes.delete(name)
end  

if model_changes.has_key?(id)
   model_changes.delete(id)
end
```

Instead of writing in two separate conditions is it possible to combine and delete the present key

Comment: Why do you have to check if the keys are present?

Comment: what if a key is not present and delete action on that particular key is called

Comment: @Hermaraj : From the Ruby docs for _Hash#delete_ : _Deletes and returns a key-value pair from hsh whose key is equal to key. If the key is not found, returns the default value._ hence, I would simply drop the test.

Answer (score 3):

You can go following way,

```
hash = { foo: :foo, bar: :bar, meh: :meh }
output = hash.except(:meh, :bar)
# => {:foo=>:foo}
```

Comment: Or `except!` to modify the hash in-place.